# How to solve the equation $\nabla f=0$ in generalized function by definition

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f\in\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\forall \phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),\forall i,f(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i})=0$. How can we get the result that $f$ is constant by the definition?

I only know the case of $n=1$, how to generalize its dimension

Comment: I guess it depends on your one-dimensional proof.

Comment: @OskarLimka But one-dimension has unique derivative

Comment: @yaoliding How is the proof for the case $n=1$?